# Mysql converts integer if too long

Tags: mysql, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to insert the number `25173545009` (11 digits) into an `INT(10)` column in a Mysql database. The strange thing is that it does not throw an error because it is too long but it converts the number to `4294967295` and inserts it into the column. Why is this happening? How does it convert `25173545009` to `4294967295`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4294967295 is the maximum value that can  be stored within an *unsigned* 32 bits(integer) Because the number is too large it basically picks the largest number it can.

Comment: You should specify that 4294967295 is the larges value that can be stored in an *unsigned* integer. 2147483648 is the largest value that can be represented with a 32 bit signed integer.

Comment: @jurgemaister you are correct, thank you for correcting.

Comment: Just a side note: `INT` is always stored on 4 bytes and it can store the maximum values displayed above that incidentally have 10 digits in decimal notation. It has nothing to do with `10` from `INT(10)`. One can declare the column as `INT(1)`, it will still be able to contain numbers up to 2^31 (signed) or 2^32 (unsigned).